# Angularjs ng-click() is not firing from ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to trigger `test()` using `ng-click` but it's not working. The `test()` function works with `ng-click` elsewhere though, so I am assuming that it has to do with the fact that it is an `ng-repeat`ed directive.

[See in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3eHAaBVMpXMt3j8lLRe7?p=preview)

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: @CodeNashor Hover over the words withing the calendar days. they turn blue. You should be able to click them to trigger the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive is using `isolated` scope, so it don't have access to it parent scope.

You need to pass the method to directive from its isolated scope using `&`

```
<div ng-repeat="day in thisMonth track by $index">
    <drop-target index="$index" day="day" method="test()"></drop-target>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app.directives.dropTarget', [])
  .directive('dropTarget', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      day: '=',
      index: '=',
      method: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: "calDay.html",
    controller: function($scope) {
      // not sure what this is
    }
  };
});
```

**Directive template**

```
<div class="dayExercise" ng-repeat="item in day.array" ng-click="method()">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FDJqwj24leq9mGWA6ApN?p=preview)

Comment: You are really fast, but I am faster :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to defint the "test" function in directive's controller (right where you wrote "//don't know what is this")

Comment: or even better, as suggested in other answers, pass the reference to the function from parent scope

Answer (score 0):

Updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/mKnX6qpxQBy20JMssWHa?p=preview

```
scope: {
        day: '=',
        index : '=',
        funcOnClick: '&'
      }
```

Your problem is a $scope problem. You have to pass the function to your directive.